# More objects with different type in one list

Tags: c#, list, object, subclass, radix

Is it possible to add more objects of different types to the same list and how do I do it?

I've got a base class and three subclasses and I want all the subclass objects in the same list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure - just create a list using the base type as the generic type argument:

```
List<Control> controls = new List<Control>();
controls.Add(new TextBox());
controls.Add(new Label());
controls.Add(new Button());
// etc
```

Note that when you retrieve the items again, you'll only "know" about them as the base type though, so you'll need to cast if you want to perform any subtype-specific operations. For example:

```
// Assuming you know that there's at least one entry...
Control firstControl = controls[0];
TextBox tb = firstControl as TextBox;
if (tb != null)
{
    // Use tb here
}
```

If you want to get *all* the elements of a particular type (or subtype thereof) you can use the `OfType<>` method:

```
foreach (TextBox tb in controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    // Use tb here
}
```

Comment: When retrieving, can't you determine the type of the control by using the `typeof()` operator again? I'm pretty confident objects don't go anonymous when they are inserted in a collection of their parent type.

Comment: @Aevitas: The objects themselves don't change type, but the *compile-time* type of (say) the indexer will be the base type. Hence the last part about having to cast back down to the subtype for any specific operations. (I don't think I'd end up using `typeof` though...)

Comment: I understand now, thanks for clearing that up! Out of curiosity, how **would** you do it then? I'd imagine myself doing something like `if (o.GetType() == typeof(OurType))` to find the "actual" type of the object.

Comment: I've tried this and it seems like a good solution but when I need my objects again, how do I know which type they are. ?

Comment: @saadan: You'd have to test - my preference would either be using `is` or `as`, depending on the situation. Or just a cast, if it would be a bug for the object to be the wrong type.

Comment: @Aevitas: As per my answer to saadan, either `is` or `as`.

Comment: When looping through your list, check of which type the object is by using `if (o.GetType() == typeof(Textbox))` for example, and if it is, cast o to that type like `return (Textbox)o;`.

Comment: @Aevitas: No, checking the exact type makes your code brittle - because then if you have some *subclass* of `TextBox` in the list, your test won't trigger even though you can still cast successfully to `TextBox`. That's why I've suggested `is` or `as`.

Comment: You could use `IsSubclassOf()` in that case, if you plan on having multiple type objects and subclasses of those objects in your lists. I'm not really sure about the `is` operator myself, [as this article points out as well](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2006/10/01/779503.aspx), it's a huge hit on memory compared to using `typeof()` and `GetType()`, and especially if you're going to work with big lists of various types and subtypes, that becomes more and more of an issue. Personally I'd only use the `is` operator when you're looking for a specific type (ie. when using reflection).

Comment: @Aevitas: Did you notice how that article specifically says that using `is` is the *preferred* method? The `typeof(string)` test is a special case as the target type is sealed. Personally I'd say that using is/as is the *idiomatic* approach. It's a shame the benchmark code is no longer available - but I'd expect `IsSubclassOf` to be even more expensive... although this is all micro-optimization anyway.

Comment: I agree Jon, it's all min/maxing. Assuming we're using the `is` operator though, and we have our type called `MyTextBox` which inherits from `Textbox`, and we'd in turn check `if (obj is Textbox) return (Textbox)obj;` (assuming obj is a `MyTextBox`) which makes perfect sense, we'd end up with a `MyTextBox` now being a `TextBox`. You could of course check if the object is a derived type before checking the "parent" types, but if you're going to do that anyway, why not use `typeof()` to begin with and save that bit of memory usage in the process?

Comment: @Aevitas: I wouldn't use `is` followed by a cast - I'd use `as` in that case. But I think you're assuming what the OP wants to do with the specific cases. I find that the number of times I explicitly want an *exact* type match is really small compared with the "compatible type" check of is/as.

Comment: Maybe it's important to note, that when using `is`, you should be checking for the more specific types first, when you are distinguishing between types, that have subtyping relationships between themselves, say you had the types `A`, `B`, `C`, where `B` and `C` both inherit from `A`, you'd want to use `obj is B/C` before  `obj is A`.

Comment: @phant0m: Yes, if you were testing for all of them. We'd really need to know more about what the OP was doing, to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have something like this:

```
public class Base { }

public class DerivedA : Base { }
public class DerivedB : Base { }
public class DerivedC : Base { }
```

You can:

```
List<Base> list = new List<Base>();
list.Add(new DerivedA);
list.Add(new DerivedB);
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can if you declare the container as a list that holds pointers to objects, that way you can downcast without problems and still have polymorphism.

Declare the list as a pointer to your base class.